# How to prove the concurrence of three lines?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> Let quadrilateral $ABCD$ inscribe in circle whose center is $O$ and let $AC$ and $BD$ intersect at $P$,while $Q$ be a point on the straight line $OP$.The circumcenters of $\Delta QAB$, $\Delta QBC$, $\Delta QCD$, $\Delta QDA$ are $O_1$, $O_2$, $O_3$, $O_4$ respectively.Then how to prove the concurrence of the straight lines $O_1 O_3$, $O_2 O_4$, $OP$?($O$ is not coincide with $P$)

I'm sorry that I can't provide any useful ideas.(I have tried to violently calculate through trigonometric functions,but it only made me crazy)

And I'm very sorry for my possible wrong grammars and strange expressions because I'm still an English learner and my first language is very different from the English system.

I'd appreciate it if someone could share his ideas about the question.

Comment: What is meant by let the quadrilateral _ABCD_ inscribe in circle _O_ ? And _O_ isn’t on the edge of the quadrilateral?

Comment: It means that the points $A,B,C,D$ are  all on the circle $O$,and the center of the circle,that is $O$, is not on each side of the quadrilateral $ABCD$.How can I express this meaning concisely and correctly?Thank you very much. @nolemonnomelon

Comment: I have managed to confirm this with a messy coordinate proof. I don't seen an obvious reason why $O$ can't lie on a side of the quad, although certainly we wouldn't want $O$ to coincide with $P$ (so, $O$ shouldn't lie on *both diagonals*; lying on *one* diagonal seems to be okay). ... @RedMaple: What is the source of this problem? If it's a textbook exercise, what topics were covered in the chapter; if a contest or online challenge, what's the audience? This will give people a sense of the skill level and kinds of techniques expected in a solution. (Add such information to the question.)

Comment: It comes from my friends.He always puts some questions online and I will try to solve it.And I guess that that's may be found when he used computer to draw for some questions.He said that this is an extension of two contest questions.Sorry that I am unable to offer any information more.@Blue

Comment: @Blue :And what you said first is probably right.I will delete that words.

Comment: I think O is the center of the circle. And the problem screams radical lines and radical center to me. So you might want to look into that.

Comment: @Blue why not share the coordinate proof?

Comment: @nolemonnomelon: *"why not share the coordinate proof?"* ... It's messy! :)  I'm looking for a way to streamline it and/or glean what it's trying to tell me about the underlying geometry, but so far it remains messy and opaque.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a slick inversive proof.

Let $(QAB)$ meet $(QCD)$ again at $X$, let $(QBC)$ meet $(QDA)$ again at $Y$. It suffices to show that the centre of $(QXY)$ (which is $O_1O_3\cap O_2O_4$) lies on $OP$.

First, note that $(QAC)$ and $(QBD)$ meet again on line $OP$. Indeed, let $(QAC)$ meet $OP$ again at $R$. Then $PQ\cdot PR=PA\cdot PC=PB\cdot PD$, which implies that $R$ lies on $(QBD)$ too.

Now invert centre $Q$ with arbitrary radius, and denote inverses with $'$. The line $OP$ is fixed, and $ABCD$ maps to another cyclic quadrilateral $A'B'C'D'$, whose center $J$ still lies on $OP$. Since $(QAC)$ and $(QBD)$ meet on $OP$, we know that $R'=A'C'\cap B'D'$ is on $OP$.

Circles $(QAB)$, $(QCD)$ map to lines $A'B'$, $C'D'$ respectively, so $X'=A'B'\cap C'D'$. Similarly, $Y'=B'C'\cap D'A'$.

But by Brokard's theorem, we know that $JR'\perp X'Y'$, i.e. $OP\perp X'Y'$. This implies that the centre of $(QXY)$ lies on $OP$, as desired.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an outline of my coordinate proof.

[image]

> **Lemma.** For $\overline{RR'}$ a diameter of $\bigcirc O$ with radius $r$, and $\overline{AA}$ a chord through $P$ with $p:=|OP|$, and $\alpha :=\angle RR'A$ and $\alpha':=\angle R'RA'$,
> $$\frac{r-p}{r+p}=\frac{(r-p)/|PA|}{(r+p)/|PA|}\quad\underbrace{\overbrace{\;\qquad=\qquad\;}^{\triangle PRA'\sim\triangle PAR'}}_{\triangle PR'A'\sim\triangle PAR}\quad\frac{|RA'|/|R'A|}{|R'A'|/|RA|}=\frac{|RA|/|R'A|}{|R'A'|/|RA'|}=\frac{\tan\alpha}{\tan\alpha'} \tag1$$

With this, and the [Inscribed Angle Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle), we can coordinatize chords $\overline{AA'}$ and $\overline{BB'}$ passing through $P$ as (abusing notation so that $\operatorname{cis}\theta=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$)
$$
A  = r \operatorname{cis} 2\alpha \qquad 
A' = r \operatorname{cis}(2\alpha'-\pi) \qquad
B  = r \operatorname{cis} 2\beta \qquad 
B' = r \operatorname{cis}(2\beta'-\pi)
\tag2$$
such that
$$\frac{\tan\alpha}{\tan\alpha'}=\frac{r-p}{r+p}=\frac{\tan\beta}{\tan\beta'}\tag3$$

With $P=(p,0)$ and $Q=(q,0)$, we find after a bit of symbol-crunching that the circumcenters of $\triangle QAB$ and $\triangle QA'B'$ are
$$\begin{align}
K\phantom{'} &:= \phantom{-}\frac{r^2 - q^2}{2((r - q) + \tan\alpha \tan\beta (r + q))} 
\;\left( 1 - \tan\alpha \tan\beta, \tan\alpha + \tan\beta\right) \tag4 \\[8pt]
K' &:= - \frac{r^2 - q^2}{2 ((r + q) + \tan\alpha' \tan\beta' (r - q))} 
\;\left( 1 - \tan\alpha' \tan\beta', \tan\alpha' + \tan\beta'\right) \tag5
\end{align}$$
Then, $\overleftrightarrow{KK'}$ meets $\overleftrightarrow{OP}$ (aka, the $x$-axis) at

> $$K_\star := \left(\frac{p (r^2-q^2)}{2 (r^2-p q)}, 0\right) \tag6$$

This is independent of $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\alpha'$, and $\beta'$. That is, it's defined *solely* by $P$ and $Q$ along a diameter of $\bigcirc O$.

Consequently, not only does $K_\star$ also lie on the line through the circumcenters of $\triangle QA'B$ and $\triangle QAB'$ (thus completing the proof), but it lies on the line through the circumcenters of *any* pair of "opposite" triangles determined by $Q$ and two chords through $P$.

In particular, taking $\overline{AA'}\perp\overline{PQ}$, and $B=A$ and $B'=A'$, we have the case where the circumcircles are internally tangent to $\bigcirc O$. This gives us a construction of $K$ as the intersection of $\overline{OA}$ with the perpendicular bisector of $\overline{QA}$ (likewise for $K'$), and we see that $K_\star$ is the projection of this point onto $\overline{PQ}$:

[image]

Be that as it may ...

The independence of $K_\star$ seems like it's trying to tell me something (ideally, something that would have helped me avoid coordinatizing the problem), but I'm not sure what it is. I may need to come back to it with fresh eyes at a later date.

Comment: With the way you parametrised your points, it looks like it could have been more natural to do the computation in complex numbers, with $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ on the unit circle.

Answer (score 0):

My friend has given his answer.I think I should present it.

Let $E=O_1O_3\cap O_2O_4$,and $F=AB\cap CD$,$G=AD∩BC$.Let $\Gamma$ be a circle whose centre is $E$,radius is $EQ$.(If $E$ is coincide with $Q$,then let $\Gamma$ be a null circle.)And $\Gamma$ meets $\bigcirc O_1$ again at $K$.

Then $FB\cdot FA=FC\cdot FD$,which implies that  $F$ is  on the radical axis of $\bigcirc O_1$ and $\bigcirc O_3$.So $FQ\perp O_1O_3$,which means $FQ\perp O_1E$.So $F$ is on the radical axis of $\bigcirc O_1$ and $\Gamma$.Then we have that $F,K,Q$ are on the same line,which implies that $FK\cdot FQ=FB\cdot FA$.Thus $F$ is on the radical axis of $\bigcirc O$ and $\Gamma$.Similarly,$G$ is on the radical axis of $\bigcirc O$ and $\Gamma$.So the straight line $FG$ is the radical axis of $\bigcirc O$ and $\Gamma$.Therefore,$OE\perp FG$.

And by Brokard's theorem,we know that $OP\perp FG$.Thus,$O,E,P$ are collinear.

So,the staight lines $O_1O_3$,$O_2O_4$ and $OP$ are concurrent at $E$.